# OSError: cannot write mode P as JPEG

Tags: python, github, youtube, reddit, moviepy

Hi i'm trying to setup this Youtube automaiton https://github.com/ClarityCoders/AutoTube.
I have deleted the Ghostscript format types in ImageMagik-6.
I'm running it on A linux Ubuntu Server and i get the Error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    redditbot.save_image(post)
  File "/home/ubuntu/AutoTube/utils/RedditBot.py", line 73, in save_image
    scale_gif(image_path, scale)
  File "/home/ubuntu/AutoTube/utils/Scalegif.py", line 19, in scale_gif
    gif.save(path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2240, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 631, in _save
    raise OSError(f"cannot write mode {im.mode} as JPEG") from e
```

OSError: cannot write mode P as JPEG

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Consider contact the creator of that code or post an issue there - https://github.com/ClarityCoders/AutoTube/issues